# Bigcommerce API PHP [Error: "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."]

Tags: php, bigcommerce

Can anyone help my code has an error and i've been solving quite some time now. the error will display  "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing." is there anyone there who encounter the same problem?

```
$tokenUrl = "https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/token";
    $connection = new Connection();
    $connection->setCipher('RC4-SHA');
    $connection->verifyPeer(false);
    $response = $connection->post($tokenUrl, array(
        "client_id" => "",
        "client_secret" => "",
        "redirect_uri" => "http://youurl.com",
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        "code" => $_GET["code"],
        "scope" => $_GET["scope"],
        "context" => $_GET["context"]
    ));

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($connection);
    print_r($response);
    echo '</pre>'
```

Comment: Are the client_id and client_secret empty because you hid the details or do you just have them blank in your code?

Comment: no i provided the client_id and client_secret and still get this error

Comment: So you have a developer account & draft app?

Comment: yes. does this still work if my url host runs on a HTTP host not on a HTTPS.

Comment: No. It has to be on https.

Comment: oh i see.. so do you think this error would be fix if i run it to a HTTPS host? anyways thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's possible. Regardless you have to be one https for it to work.